Override default value in Radix-UI components/themes
I’m constructing an interface with Next.JS and Radix-UI.
By default on the design, the links are underlined, the text is a size 2, etc. but the default value in the components are underlined="auto" or size="3", things like that.
I think I’ve been missing something obvious, but what I wish to do is to override those values without having to create custom components, like a config file, or I don’t know ? I don’t want to create custom styles, the UI designer is using RadixUI Figma theme, and I get all the datas like spacing, size, etc. in it, and I don’t want to mess with this.
Thank you for being kind enough to look at my question.
I am under the impression it’s a simple thing, but can’t put my finger on it.
I searched on Google with "radix-ui override default values for components"
I have created custom component with my default values

What are you use to override the style ? tailwind or css modules ? Have you checked the component API docs ? I think we need more use cases and code example
